# How to get a native-like English style of speaking ?

Tags: american-english, style, dialect

So this might be a common question for non-native speakers, how to speak like English american natives ?!

I've been using a podcast that is fairly good but it doesn't contain all various aspects of a daily life, that's why I was wondering that it might be the question of many other English learners as well.

The most problematic issue we face with learning English, there may be a lot of people who don't want to speak like natives though. That's not my case 'cause I really like the language and I'm sure so many others feel the same.

By the way, Is there any website or any other methods to fulfill the aim?
Even once I was trying to find the curriculum of schools in US to find out how to kind of put my feet on natives shoes, But I faced a bigger problem.
long story short, I feel like I'm done with the grammar and I think it's about time to step further and be just like them, I'm even trying to memorize songs and lyrics but I guess that won't fly with the daily life.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for resources

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's also too broad, unfortunately, a subject for an entire website, not a single question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend once said "The only way to really learn a language is lying down". What he meant was that the only way to get a detailed knowledge of a language is to live with a native.

Comment: It's called a "sleeping dictionary".

Comment: .. plus sleeping pronunciation benchmark, plus idiomatic speech guide, plus conversation class,...  the list goes on..

Comment: And before you get your plane tickets, be sure to choose the part of America that has the accent/style that you like. They aren't all the same (though I am pretty sure I don't have any accent at all).